# Implicit conversions in boolean compound assignment?

Tags: c++, boolean, language-lawyer, implicit-conversion

I would like to understand what happens in the following cases :

```
bool b = false;
float f = 3.14;
char c = 1;
int i = 2;
unsigned int u = 3;
long long int ll = 4;
unsigned long long int ull = 5;

b += f;
b += c;
b += i;
b += u;
b += ll;
b += ull;

b &= f;
b &= c;
b &= i;
b &= u;
b &= ll;
b &= ull;

b <<= f;
b <<= c;
b <<= i;
b <<= u;
b <<= ll;
b <<= ull;
```

Or in other words, what are the implicit conversions that are done according to the standard?

Other questions: would the result be the same, if the only provided signature of compound assignment for an hypothetical `bool` class would be of the form:

```
class bool {bool& operator op=(int x) noexcept;}; // op <=> +,-,&,|...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The relevant conversion in all of these cases is a Boolean conversion, [conv.bool]:

> A prvalue of arithmetic, unscoped enumeration, pointer, or pointer to member type can be converted to a
>   prvalue of type `bool`. A zero value, null pointer value, or null member pointer value is converted to `false`;
>   any other value is converted to `true`. For direct-initialization (8.5), a prvalue of type `std::nullptr_t` can
>   be converted to a prvalue of type `bool`; the resulting value is `false`.

With two exceptions:

```
b &= f;
b <<= f;
```

The former, because of [expr.bit.and]:

> The usual arithmetic conversions are performed; the result is the bitwise AND function of the operands. The
>   operator **applies only to integral or unscoped enumeration operands**.

and the latter, because of [expr.shift]:

> The operands **shall be of integral or unscoped enumeration type** and integral promotions are performed.

Since `float` is neither integral nor of unscoped enumeration type, those two operations are invalid.

---

In the case of your (and I'm renaming your class here):

```
class Bool {Bool& operator op=(int x) noexcept;}; // op <=> +,-,&,|...
```

we would instead fall into one of three conversions, depending on the types. For `char` or `bool`, we do an Integral Promotion, [conv.prom]:

> A prvalue of an integer type other than `bool`, `char16_t`, `char32_t`, or `wchar_t` whose integer conversion
>   rank (4.13) is less than the rank of int can be converted to a prvalue of type int if `int` can represent all
>   the values of the source type; otherwise, the source prvalue can be converted to a prvalue of type `unsigned
>   int`.
>   [...]
>   A prvalue of type `bool` can be converted to a prvalue of type `int`, with `false` becoming zero and `true`
>   becoming one.

For the other integral types, Integral Conversion, from [conv.integral]:

> A prvalue of an integer type can be converted to a prvalue of another integer type. A prvalue of an unscoped
>   enumeration type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type.
>   [...]
>   If the destination type is signed, the value is unchanged if it can be represented in the destination type;
>   otherwise, the value is implementation-defined.

And for `float`, a Floating-Integral Conversion, from [conv.fpint]:

> A prvalue of a floating point type can be converted to a prvalue of an integer type. The conversion truncates;
>   that is, the fractional part is discarded. The behavior is undefined if the truncated value cannot be
>   represented in the destination type.

Answer (score 0):

For compound assignment expressions, the right operand is first converted to the left operand's type (C++14 5.17 p3):

> If the left operand is not of class type, the expression is implicitly converted (Clause 4) to the cv-unqualified type of the left operand.

Because of this, the equivalent hypothetical operator should take a bool parameter:

```
class bool {bool& operator op=(bool x) noexcept;};
```

Here's an example where it would make a difference if you used `int` instead:

```
#include <iostream>

struct Bool {
  bool value;

  Bool(bool value) : value(value) { }
  Bool &operator += (int x) noexcept { value += x; return *this; }
};

int main()
{
  Bool fake_bool = false;
  bool real_bool = false;

  fake_bool += 0.1;
  real_bool += 0.1;
  std::cout << fake_bool.value << "\n";
  std::cout << real_bool << "\n";
}
```

outputs

```
0
1
```